# ValidationError: Collection2 validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., email: Path `email` is required., message: Path `message` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have to receive message from the visitor on the website

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("MongoDb-Connection-Uri")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("mongodb connected");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("failed to connect");
  });

const LoginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const collection = mongoose.model("Collection2", LoginSchema);

module.exports = collection; // Export the collection model
```

I have tried **commenting the required or setting it to false** and **adding the bodyParser**. But I want these fields on my mongodb online. After exporting this collection to my main js file I do the following

```
// Send Message receive details
app.post("/",async (req,res)=>{
    const data={
        name :req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        message:req.body.message
    }
    await collection.insertMany([data]);
    const responseHTML=`<script> alert("${"Your msg is sent"}"); </script>` ;
    res.sendFile("C:\\Users\\acool\\Desktop\\myPortfolio-master\\index.html");
    res.send(responseHTML);
    
})
```

I am very new to this. Any help would be deeply appreciated

I have tried adding bodyParser.
I have removed the required:true but then it these fileds arent saved on the database
I have tried saving the document but I want it to be user entered on the website.

Answer (score 0):

required: true in mongoose means that filed will always be provided. if you remove require: true, you can add default: "" for it to show in your database. Always remember that if you are not using findAndUpdate() in mongoose then you have to `save()` before any response. in your case

```
const myCollection = await collection.insertMany([data]);
await myCollection.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure you are using the body-parser in your app.js/server.js/index.js or wherever your main file is like so:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true} ));
app.use(express.json());
```

Secondly, Mongoose has a specific method for creating a new document. The [Model.create](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.create()) is preferred for inserting one document. The `insertMany` is perfectly valid but semantically it doesn't make sense to use `insertMany` just to insert one document. In your case it looks like `create` would be more appropriate. Here is a sample of it's use within a `try/catch` block for better error handling:

```js
app.post('/', async (req, res) =>{
   console.log(req.body); //< Make sure data is parsed and present in req.body
   try{
      const {name, email, message} = req.body;
      const newMessage = await collection.create({name, email, message});
      res.status(200).json({
         newMessage : newMessage
      });
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err); //< Check what went wrong on server
      res.status(400).json({
         error : 'Appropriate error message sent to front-end'
      });
   }
});
```

An alternative to `Model.create()` would be construct the document first using a new instance of the Model and then calling `save()` on that new instance like so:

```js
app.post('/', async (req, res) =>{
   console.log(req.body); //< Make sure data is parsed and present in req.body
   try{
      const {name, email, message} = req.body;
      const newMessage = new collection({ name, email, message });
      await newMessage.save();
      res.status(200).json({
         newMessage : newMessage
      });
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err); //< Check what went wrong on server
      res.status(400).json({
         error : 'Appropriate error message sent to front-end'
      });
   }
});
```

You can read more [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works if I open localhost. Although when i Go Live on VS code using my main html page this isn't working. It redirects me to HTTP Error 405.

Comment: The 405 error means method not allowed. Which method is not allowed GET/POST/PUT etc? You may need to do some configuration with VS Code Live and post a new question. I'm sure someone on here will be able to help you debug. If you found this answer useful please consider [marking as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.).